# ssh to EC2 instance with the new root user created

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

After creating EC2 instance ssh to server is granted. But I created a root user(newUser) in ubuntu server.Now I want to directly ssh to the server with the new root user created. Using the same ssh command with the new user is denied.

`ssh -i <.pem> newUser@ec2----.amazon.com` is denied.

Comment: Did you setup passwordless ssh for the newUser? Which .pem file are you using the login as the newUser?

Comment: I`m using the AWS generated key .pem file and yes I been trying with the above command and it didn't prompt me for the password. Do I have to pass any arguments ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup password-less ssh for the new user `newUser`.

The following SO overflow question would help - https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

Assuming your EC2 instance is an Ubuntu instance, the private key that you are trying to use to login would only work for logging in as the user `ubuntu`.

This thread on AWS forums would also be helpful - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=86876